# $f : X\longrightarrow Y$ isomorphism $ \Rightarrow (?)\, \, f^*:Div(Y)\longrightarrow Div(X)$ isomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold. Denote by Div$(X)$ the Weil divisors group of $X$.

We have to:

Let $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a holomorphic map of connected
complex manifolds and suppose that $f$ is dominant, i.e. $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$.
Then the pull-back defines a group homomorphism 
$$
f^* :Div(Y) \longrightarrow Div(X).
$$

Question: If $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ is an analytic isomorphism ( bi-holomorphic map), then is it true that $f^*:Div(Y)\longrightarrow Div(X)$ is a group isomorphism?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse map gives rise to a map on Div's in the opposite direction. Since $\text{Div}(\cdot)$ is functorial, and composition of $f$ with its inverse gives the identity map, this means that the map on Div's is inverse to the original one.

Comment: $D=\sum a_iZ_i $, where $Z_i$ is irreduible hypersurfaces... $(f^{-1})^*(f^*(Z_i))=Z_i$ this is where you use that Div(⋅) is functorial? Because that must be true, to close the argument. Right?

Comment: Correct. But you can rerphase this to work in great generality. Anytime a map is functorial, an isomorphism in the source category induces an isomorphism in the target via this argument.

Comment: Also, just to make sure, the functorality statement here is $g^* \circ f^* = (f \circ g)^*$.

Comment: Helped me a lot! Thanks :)